# How to programmatically print ESCPOS receipt?

Tags: c++, printing, usb, libusb, escpos

**Background**

I am relatively new to UNIX-like operating systems and a beginner at best in MacOS, so I might have it all wrong but here it is.

I have attached to a project where the goal is to programmatically utilize a thermal printer via USB or RS232 for receipt outputs. I need to use ESCPOS commands to print receipt.

**Details**

I have connected my printer to MacBook via USB. I can confirm that OS is picking up USB device: It appears in System Report. Also, followed this [post](https://mike42.me/blog/2015-10-how-to-connect-a-usb-receipt-printer-up-on-mac-os-x) to setup CUPS.

I am using [escpospp](https://github.com/Malanche/escpospp) lib, this is the code for printing a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "escpospp/escpospp.h"

int main(){
    try{
        Printer::initializePrinter(std::pair<int,int>(0x04b8,0x0e03));
        Printer &printer = Printer::getPrinter();
        printer.text("This is a **sample** text!\n");
        printer.cut();
    } catch (int e){
        //There was an error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the values at `Printer::initializePrinter(std::pair<int,int>(0x04b8,0x0e03));` to correctly point to my device by checking System Report output.

When I try to run, I got `Cannot open device`. This is an error from underlying libusb.

*Note: I can print using `lpr` command.*

**Question**

It is clear that I am doing something wrong or missed something along the way. How can I programmatically send ESCPOS commands to a connected USB thermal printer in MacOS with above details?

Comment: I looked into the repo you provided as link: [`Printer.cpp`](https://github.com/Malanche/escpospp/blob/master/src/Printer.cpp). (I hoped to find any doc. of the parameters.) The `Printer::initializePrinter()` doesn't do anything with the `std::pair<int, int> ids` parameter. Confusing, isn't it? May be, subject of future extension? You could contact the author regarding this.

Comment: @Scheff Yup, you beat me to it. I did the same and saw it. I like to believe it was a happy accident. Anyway, I created an issue in repo.

Comment: So, if the lib. works for others but not for you, then something else must be there which fails in your case. May be, you try to find out with debugger where it actually accesses the USB and how.

Comment: I don't think EscPospp lib will work for anyone with different VendorId and ProductId. It is clearly an issue of EscPospp lib, not libusb. To confirm, I cloned EscPospp repo to local and revised code to forward params to libusb. Now it works as intended and I don't know what to do with question now :/